# Constants in Idris

Tags: idris

What's an idiomatic way to define what we call a constant in other languages in Idris? Is it this?

```
myConstant : String
myConstant = "some_constant1"


myConstant2 : Int
myConstant2 = 123
```

If so, in REPL I get an exception after declaration:

```
 (input):1:13: error: expected: "$",
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is an idiomatic way of defining constants in Idris (in source files).

However, when binding a name in REPL, you need to use the `:let` directive with explicit type annotations like this:

```
Idris> :let myConstant : String; myConstant = "some_constant1"
```

or sometimes Idris is able to infer the type:

```
Idris> :let myConstant = "some_constant1"
```

It is described [here](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/repl.html#adding-let-bindings).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special in declaring global constants. The way you do it is the ok way.

> If so, in REPL I get an exception after declaration:

Which version of Idris are you using? On 1.0 everything works fine for me.
How do you declare variables? In file and than you're loading file in REPL?

Comment: `Idris version 1.0`. I declare it in repl directly